# My program is exiting with return value 3221225620

Tags: c++

I have written a cpp code for array rotation and the file handling part is a bit tricky for me.
The code itself is correct but even though the files are in the same directory as the code it is not working for some reason

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int ar[100];
// #define crap ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
 
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b);
}
void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
{
    d = d % n;
    int g_c_d = gcd(d, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < g_c_d; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        int j = i;
 
        while (1) {
            int k = j + d;
            if (k >= n)
                k = k - n;
 
            if (k == i)
                break;
 
            arr[j] = arr[k];
            j = k;
        }
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

//int *func(int m)
//{
//  int *p;
//  p=new int[m];
//  return (p);
//}

int main()
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); 
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif

    // crap;
    int n,d;
    cin>>n>>d;
    // ar=func(n);
    // cout<<sizeof(ar);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    leftRotate(ar, d, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << ar[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

The code itself is working and returning correct output in the terminal but I cant seem to find the issue here
I have tried without file handling and it was giving a return value 3221225620 at the terminal
sample input is:

5 2
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Where do you see the return value?

Comment: What inputs are you giving? If `n > 100` you'll write outside the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here shows a possible error:

`3221225620 (0xC0000094): Zero Division Error`

means that a divisor in your code could sometime be zero.

as for your code(line 20: `d = d % n;`), when your `n` is `0`, the output will show `return value 3221225620`

so please check your data in `"input.txt"`

Comment: Here `n` is the size of array and its always non zero. Even so I am getting the right answer in the terminal without file handling I am doing something wrong there!

Comment: @Rohith_3330 `n` is not the size of the array, it is the data that comes from `std::cin`. Please check your inputs.

Comment: @Rohith_3330 the point is your inputs in "input.txt". i've tried your sample input in a "input.txt", and then got the right "output.txt" with "3 4 5 1 2 " inside. so make sure <1>you don't get a typo in the file name <"input.txt">. <2>you DO have the sample inputs in the file<"input.txt">. any of them means cin>>n with 0, and could raise this error.